# What is the index argument from the __getitem__(...) method in tf.keras.utils.Sequence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

**TLDR;** Made a custom tf.keras.utils.Sequence [[1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence)] to load batched data into `keras.model.fit(...)`. Generator had considerably worse performance than when model is called on data loaded from memory, even though hyperparameters/model/data structure is the same. Model was overfitting so was wondering if the index argument from the `model.fit(...)` [[2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)] method to the `__getitem__(..., index)` method in the generator causes the same images to be fed to the model multiple times? **How is the index argument selected? is it ordered? is the max index controlled by the `__len(...)__`?**

**References**

1. [tf.keras.utils.Sequence](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence)
2. [keras.model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

I am using a subclass of tf.keras.utils.Sequence [[1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence)] to feed batches of data to the model.fit(...) method, shown below.

```
class Generator(Sequence):
    
    def __init__(self, df, x, y, file_type, req_dim, directory, batch_size):
        # data info
        self.df = df
        self.x = self.df[x]  # path list to images being loaded
        self.y = self.df[y]  # corresponding target values
        self.index = self.df.index.to_list()
        self.directory = directory  # directory where features images are stored 
        self.file_type = file_type  # dictate which type of image to load 
        # for batches
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        """
        :returns number of batches per epoch
        """
        return int(np.floor(len(self.df) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        receives call from keras (index) and grabs corresponding data batch
        :param index:
        :return:
        """
        # instantiate output array
        x = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.req_dim))

        # batches
        batch_x = self.x[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size].to_numpy()
        batch_y = self.y[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size].to_numpy(dtype=float)

        for i in batch_x:

            # logic to load images + perform operations on them
            im = load(...)
            im = operations(im)
            
            x[i, ] = im  # makes batches of ims

        return tuple((x, batch_y.reshape(-1, 1)))
```

Traditionally i have loaded the data directly into memory but have needed to use the above Sequence subclass (similar to a generator, will refer to as generator moving forward) to deal with larger file sizes. To test if the generator worked i used data that could be loaded both directly into memory *and* with the generator. The results from data loaded into memory are consistent with previous experiments while using the generator causes the model to over-fit on the training data.

Since the model was overfitting i was wondering if the index argument input in the`__getitem__(self, index)`, which is sent by keras to retrieve a given batch number, was ordered or if it can cause a single image to be read in multiple times?

The generator is used in the below pseudo code:

```
# load data
data = load_data(...)

# split data according to batch size used later so that each split has an equal number of samples when 
# divided into batches
train, test, val = train_test_split(data) 

scaler = Scaler()
train['target'] = scaler.fit_transform(train['target'])
test['target'] = scaler.transform(test['target'])
val['target'] = scaler.transform(val['target'])

# instantiate generator
train_gen = DataGenerator(train, x='feature_name', y='target', file_type, dims, directory, batch_size=5)

# load validation images and targets directly to memory
val_x = load(...)
val_y = val['target'].to_numpy(dtype=float)


model = model_1(*dims)  # Convolutional neural network that takes in height, width, depth args

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5, decay=1e-5/400), loss=LogCosh())

history = model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=(val_x, val_y)

pred = model.pred(test)
```

Comment: Would like to know this also...

Comment: I am also interested in this. Especially since I am trying to read sequences with two generators inside my custom generator and I don't want the shuffle at the end of epoch to mess up the sequences.

Comment: as I know keras takes the whole data in form of tensor (tensor_from_slices) or iterate generator's output (from_generator)  according __len__ internally!.. & __getitem__ takes one batch returned

Answer (score 2):

I think the index number of `__getitem__` is related to the total amount of the samples and the batch_size you assigned.

For example, I'm playing with fer2013plus dataset now and for testing I have 3944 images. My test_generator is created like this:

```
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                                  target_size=(48,48),
                                                  color_mode='grayscale',
                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                  class_mode='categorical')
```

When I call `test_generator.__getitem__()`, the index is 0 to 123. Otherwise the err pops out as `ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 124, but the Sequence has length 124`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a reproducibility issue when I used a custom datagenerator. The problem was solved when I set the parameter shuffle=False:

```
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=1, shuffle=False)
```

I think the method does not ignore the shuffle parameter when using a date generator as promised in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).